# How to check how many files in folder - by croned script in MAC OS X

Tags: file, email, terminal, cron

I have this problem:

I'm bored by constantly checking if there are new subtitles for my favourite tv series and i want to create something what inform me when it will be available.

There is an idea:

i'm checking if there are subtitles for my tv series file. e:
(Qnapi is an app to download any subtitles)

```
open -a QNapi.app my.favourite.tvseries.mp4 
delay 20
killall QNapi
```

then i need to do something like this:

```
if (count(files) > 1) then
mail "There are subtitles!", "my@email.com", "myother@email.com"
```

And then i need to put this in a hourly executed loop.

I belive i can handle with loop but how to check files count in folder and put this whole thing into .sh file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have this for now:

```
open -a Qnapi.app mytvseries.mp4
sleep 5
killall QNapi
sleep 5

FCOUNT="$(ls -1 | wc -l)"

if [ "${FCOUNT}" -gt 2 ]
then
    echo "There's Beans"
fi
```